# What classification method to use

Tags: classification, python

I have two sets of data from two experiments. All data can be divided in three classes, e.g.:

$$\begin{array}{cccc}\rm{Parameter}1&\rm{Parameter}2 ...&\rm{Parameter}N&\rm{Class}\\\hline a_1&b_1&c_1&A\\a_2&b_2&c_2&B\\a_3&b_3&c_3&C\\...\end{array}$$

The values of the parameters define a class. I want to develop criteria based on one data set (with preassigned classes) so that I could assign classes to the second data set.
As all the parameters have a certain meaning, I would not like to have a 'black box' method like neural networks, but I would like to have something like, "If Parameter1 is less than X and Parameter2 is within the interval [Y,Z] then it is class A."

What is the best way to do it? Is there an implementation of such a way in Python?

Answer (score 4):

You are looking for a **[decision tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_tree)**. It will produce exactly this "if this then that" type of rules that you are looking for. Other methods, such as SVM, will produce a result that may work better, but that will be hard to *explain*.

You really should read a book, or Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_classification

Comment: And for a non-subject-matter-driven decision tree the sample size required to yield reliable structure will be extremely high unless the signal:noise ratio is very high.

Comment: The free ebook [Elements of
Statistical Learning](http://statweb.stanford.edu/~tibs/ElemStatLearn/) covers various classification methods and their use with R.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do this in Python, [scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/) has a nice Decision Tree implementation. Learn more here:

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/tree.html

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, what you are after is semi-supervised learning: you learn a few, previously labelled samples, and then label the remaining unlabelled samples with the help of the trained classifier.

There are a number of approaches to this problem. A very popular one are Transductive Support Vector Machines, first introduced in this [paper](http://www1.cs.columbia.edu/~dplewis/candidacy/joachims99transductive.pdf) by T. Joachim. It is implemented in [SVMlight](http://svmlight.joachims.org/) (which happens to be developed by the author of the previous paper).

Another option are manifold learning algorithms like isomap or tSNE, to name just two of them.